Правильность пунктуации в предложении с уточнением (или, точнее) и вставной конструкцией
Предложение из современной художественной литературы:
Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две — спальня и кабинет — находится в самом конце коридора, дальше идти некуда.
Интересует запятая перед ИЛИ и оформление вставки (наличие запятых) по правилам Розенталя или ПАС.
Или хотя бы без правил)

Никто  и ничего не знает? Кончился золотой век, да и серебряный тоже)

Основа:
Моя комната находится в самом конце коридора.
Добавляем пояснение (как бы второе название комнаты):
Моя комната, или мой отсек, находится в самом конце коридора.
Вставляем в пояснение вводное слово:
Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек, находится в самом конце коридора.
Вводим объяснение пояснения (почему отсек), закрываем его запятой:
Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две, находится в самом конце коридора.
Еще больше накручиваем (уточняем, какие именно две комнаты). Второе тире не нужно. Добавляем конечное предложение, не участвующее в основе, и получаем:
Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две — спальня и кабинет, находится в самом конце коридора, дальше идти некуда.
Вариант:
Моя комната (или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две — спальня и кабинет) находится в самом конце коридора, дальше идти некуда.

Спасибо за ответ!  Вы используете правило обособления приложений (не вставок), пункт 10, примечание 1. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: 1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111  Очень разумно!  // Теперь о союзе ИЛИ. Вы оставляете запятую перед союзом, а почему? Какой у вас союз? По Розенталю вроде разделительный, а тогда запятая не нужна. Розенталь, пункт 2, примечание 1  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119  В то же время пауза там не исключена, но как объяснить?

Посмотрел примечание. Там как раз подходит пояснит. союз, т. е. когда второе название поясняет первое (флексия, или окончание), а разделительный разделяет два разных понятия, как в примере: Трудно или, точнее, скучно.

Но разве это тождество? Ведь комната - это не отсек. Нельзя сказать: комната, то есть отсек. Идет подбор подходящего слова для помещения. Как и здесь: трудно или, точнее, скучно.  Флексия, или окончание - это общепринятые термины.  В общем,  я не уверена)  Я думаю, может, посчитать ИЛИ присоединительным союзом.

Это не тождество в прямом смысле, но и не разные вещи. У меня не клеится без запятой. Повторить союз нельзя: Или моя комната, или мой отсек. Рассказчик говорит об отсеке как о комнате.

Ну хорошо, пусть будет так.  Все-таки с этими союзами не всегда все однозначно ясно.

Дополнение к ответу
Думаю,что Роман все-таки прав относительно пояснительного союза ИЛИ. Но мне нужно сформулировать по возможности четкое правило по этой теме.

Мы говорим о двух названиях для одного предмета (разделительный союз ИЛИ)

Такое помещение из двух комнат можно назвать отсеком. Это, точнее, не комната, а отсек из двух комат. Сравнить с правилами: Эту морфему называют окончанием или флексией. Разделительный союз ИЛИ.

Мы применяем  два названия в тексте (пояснительный союз ИЛИ)

Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек,  находится в самом конце коридора. Сравнить с правилами: Флексия, или окончание, имеется не у всех слов. Пояснительный союз ИЛИ.

Еще один вариант оформления со вставкой (вариант со скобками был в ответе):

Моя комната — или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две, спальня и кабинет, — находится в самом конце коридора, дальше идти некуда.
Вставка хороша тем, что выделяется вся дополнительная информацию как одно сообщение.
P. S. Интересное предложение, было о чем подумать. Поэтому еще раз спасибо Роману за участие в обсуждении и помощь. Для меня такие вопросы отнюдь не развлечение, как можно считать. Я составляю конспект по практике письма (уж точно мой авторский, в отличие от теоретической части). И на  форуме очень много полезной информации (наше общее достижение).

У Вас: "Такое помещение из двух комнат можно назвать отсеком. Это, точнее, не комната, а отсек из двух комат". Как такое может быть? )  Я понял так и по-другому не представляю: всего 2 комнаты, а конце коридора есть какая-то перегородка, это и есть "моя комната", или "мой отсек".

Может, и так, это непринципиально. Важно, что разделительный союз ИЛИ используется в других рассуждениях: это не комната, а отсек и т .д. А в этом тексте предмет назван два раза разными словами (признак пояснения). А вообще там страшная детективная история.

Из темного коридора навстречу мне, откуда ни возьмись, появился Саша и быстро прошел — чтобы не сказать прошмыгнул — мимо, не говоря ни слова. Я не успел разглядеть его лица. Для того чтобы понять, что меня смутило, надо знать расположение комнат в нашей квартире. Моя комната, или, точнее, мой отсек, потому что комнат там две — спальня и кабинет — находится в самом конце коридора, дальше идти некуда. А между тем Саша именно оттуда и шел. Конечно, можно было предположить, что он просто бродит в задумчивости взад-вперед по коридору, но  вернее то, что он вышел из моей комнаты. Нацкорпус.

Ну вот, последнее предложение объясняет, что комната-отсек находится в коридоре, а не состоит из двух комнат.
